# What is the difference between an empty class (which is not an element) and an empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

By using contradictions, in set theory we prove that an empty class

$$C = \{ x : x \text{ does not belong to } x \}$$ is not an element. By using the Axiom of Infinity and the empty set $\emptyset$, we can build the set of natural numbers. An empty class contains no elements and an empty set also contains no elements. How are they different?

Comment: The first sentence makes no sense to me. What do you mean? In most set/class theories the empty set/class is unique. The $C$ in your post is not the usual definition of empty set/class.

Comment: In fact $C$ is the **proper class** of all sets in NBG set theory.

Comment: What makes you think $C$ is empty? Do you believe that every set is an element of itself?

Comment: The empty class is classier.